# "le fameux" ou "la fameuse" E=mc² ?

Tags: usage, adjectifs, genre, science

> Au cours du XXe siècle, on a découvert au niveau sub-atomique que la
>   masse est aussi une forme d'énergie ; ainsi le fameux / la fameuse
>   E=mc²  liant masse et énergie.

Je me demande quelle forme il faut utiliser : le fameux (forme neutre ?) ou la fameuse (équation ?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut se passer du terme générique dans le cas où il s'agit d'une personne, d'un personnage de légende et dans d'autres cas, comme celui de certaines machines qui ont un nom mais pas, il me semble, dans celui des équations ; dire « la fameuse F=GmM/r² » ou « la fameuse PV=nRT » par exemple ne  me semble pas naturel, et il en va de même pour toutes les équations ; de plus on peu catégoriser ces équations différemment avec par exemple des adjectif comme « énigmatique », « simple » et d'autres ; si on fait une règle de permettre de ne pas utiliser le terme générique on pourrait dire « l'énigmatique E=mc² » », « la simple E=mc² » », ce qui semble très peu naturel. Il semble que l'on dise plus naturellement « la formule/l'équation énigmatique « E=mc² » », la simple formule/équation E=mc² ». Donc, en conclusion on peut dire que l'on aurait à faire des exceptions, à commencer par « fameuse » et « E=mc² ». Ce qui entraine cet état de chose (un certain manque de logique) c'est que les formules ne sont pas des symboles du langage, ce ne sont  pas des noms, ce sont en fait des phrases tournées en symbolisme mathématique. En résumé le procédé grammatical est celui d'une phrase comme la suivante ;

> Elle venait d'entendre le fameux « Tire la bobinette et la chevillette cherra. » et compris qu'elle pouvait entrer dans la pièce.

D'ailleurs on n'a aucun moyen de savoir si l'on doit dire « le fameux » ou « la fameuse » ; c'est une phrase, c'est aussi une réponse, mais c'est tout aussi bien un énoncé. Il en va de même pour l'équation ; sans spécifier, on peut l'appeler du symbolisme et alors on doit dire « le fameux symbolisme « E=mc² » ». L'absence d'un terme générique, donc, défie les règle des accords ; bien sûr il y a une forte propension à considérer la chose en tant que formule ou  équation et très peu en tant qu'autre chose ; cependant cela relève plutôt de l'arbitraire ; après tout je peux assumer que l'on doit comprendre cette ellipse et écrire « le fameux « E=mc² » ». Cet état de chose me porte à croire qu'il est préférable d'utiliser un terme générique et des guillemets. Il faudrait dire et écrire donc selon ce point de vue « le fameux symbolisme  « E=mc² » », ou « la fameuse formule « E=mc² » » ou « la fameuse équation « E=mc² » ».

Answer (score 5):

Personnellement, j'accorderai l'adjectif avec le nom, soit :

> la fameu**se** [équation] E=mc<sup>2</sup> liant masse et énergie.

Comment: De même, l'idée qui vient en premier, est de dire que E=mc² est UNE formule, UNE équation, UNE fonction, même si on pourrait éventuellement dire UN énoncé.

Answer (score 3):

J'accorderai également en conséquence puisque le mot équation ou formule est sous-entendu dans cette phrase et qu'il est de genre féminin.